# What is the best place to start learning Qt?

Tags: qt

I can't find a good place to start. It is such a large framework I don't know where to begin. Should it be GUI development using Qt Creator and all of those tutorials? There are just so many... Where do you start with Qt?

P.S. Do you pronounce it "Cute"?

Edit: I have Qt Creator installed and all of the Qt documentation is built in. The problem is there is just so much. The page mentioned below says to buy the book and start doing some tutorials. The problem is none of the tutorials seem to say "Start here for people who have NEVER seen Qt before and don't even really know what it is"

Comment: Yes, it is pronounced as "cute" : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(toolkit)

Comment: Officially it's "cute", but from my experience most American users call it "QT" - you can use whichever you like.

Comment: I call it Qt and I'm British English...

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NbTEVbQLC8s -- These guys calls Qt 4 "Cute four" (while dancing!).

Comment: http://qmlbook.github.io/ This is a free book about Qt5, could view as html online or download as pdf freely.

Comment: I pronounce Qt like "cue tee"

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Have you had a look at the awesome Qt documentation? :)
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/how-to-learn-qt.html
This page gives you some pointers on how to get started.
You'll definitely want to bookmark http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/index.html

In my opinion there's no right end to start from - where you should start depends on what you want to do with Qt. But if you're going to create GUIs then GUI creation and programming is a good start.. I'd advice you to have a look at the Qt demo app, explore the parts of Qt and then do a few tutorials.

Usually I learn by implementing something. Have an idea of what I want to do, then implement it whilst reading documentation.

Comment: There's been some reshuffling since this answer was accepted, and those links are now out of date. The Qt documentation is now here: http://qt-project.org/doc/

Comment: I'd also suggest to browse around an example to see how things are done. http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/examples/xml/rsslisting/rsslisting.cpp.html#_ZN10RSSListingC1EP7QWidget .. also edit it, compile it, see what changed.

Answer (score 18):

My vote is for VoidRealms video tutorials:
http://www.youtube.com/user/voidrealms

Answer (score 15):

I find this website a great place to start http://zetcode.com/gui/qt4/

It basically provides short tutorials on a number of topics, which are self-contained and really easy to follow. I learnt Win32API GUI programming this way, and GTK. From trying out what I want from the tutorial, I then start looking for what do I want to do that's not in the tutorial? Google and sites like this then become my best friend...!

Start small - how to build / link a basic window in Qt. How to add things to it. How best to organise files etc. Then build up to what you want. Break the problem down.

I usually go by hand to start off with, with everything. This is because IDEs (Glade, Eclipse, NetBeans, Visual Studio) tend to generate a whole lot of code that I never understood as a beginner.

Edit - with the above tutorial, if you are on Linux, ignore the download bit in the tutorial and just go for the version of qt4-devel in your repositories.

Answer (score 9):

When I started to develop in Qt (I pronounce QT, I'm French Canadian) I bought the book [C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4 (second edition)](http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=9780132354165) by Jasmin Blanchette and Mark Summerfield.
Most of what you will find in the book is well covered in the Qt tutorials but I do like to read books (and spent some time away of my computer if I can).

Another good resource is ICSNetwork for Qt screencasts: http://www.ics.com/learning/icsnetwork/

And, finally, a good place to meet other Qt Developers is at [Qt Centre Forum](http://www.qtcentre.org). You will find there a Forum, a Wiki, Documentation, Links, News and more about Qt.

Answer (score 8):

I learned from here:  *Introduction to Design Patterns in C++ with Qt4*
([PDF](http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/9780131879058/downloads/0131879057_Ezust_book.pdf) version.  Wayback machine [archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20121104000313/http://cartan.cas.suffolk.edu/oopdocbook/opensource/index.html) version.)

Answer (score 3):

I used 'Foundations of Qt Development' by Johan Thelin.