# New to QT help needed

Tags: qt, qt4, symbian, qt-creator

i am new to QT, i don't have any knowledge about it.
from scratch i need to learn, if you people have some tutorials or some technical blogs please
feel free to share with me..
i have seen some stuffs in troltech, tell me any thing else apart from it.

Thanks

Comment: trolltech's docs and tutorials are really good.

Comment: yeah. Qt's documentation is probably the best documentation i've ever seen.

Comment: How can you be so clueless when the Qt documentation is so great and includes all the tutorials you need?

Comment: It sounds like a duplicate question ;-) .... see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184563/i-want-to-start-qt/2185052#2185052](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184563/i-want-to-start-qt/2185052#2185052) or [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169950/what-is-the-best-place-to-start-learning-qt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169950/what-is-the-best-place-to-start-learning-qt) Hope it helps !

Comment: For some insight into QT and Symbian OS: http://www.symsource.com/blog/archives/109

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trolltech [documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/index.html) is great.

I can also suggest having a look at [the independant tutorial](http://www.digitalfanatics.org/projects/qt_tutorial/).

There are also some great books about Qt. My favourite is [C++ Gui programming with Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/developer/books/cpp-gui-programming-with-qt-4-2nd-edition).

Check out also these websites : [Qt Forum](http://www.qtforum.org/) and  [Qt Center](http://qtcentre.org).

Comment: Just notice that the independant tutorial is aimed at Qt 3. It still applies to much of Qt, but not all. The Qt 4 version turned into the Foundations of Qt Development, available from Apress.

Answer (score 1):

This book is nice to start with Qt (Assuming you know c++)

[http://www.amazon.com/Book-Qt-Art-Building-Applications/dp/1593271476/ref=sr_1_9?ie=UTF8&qid=1301423092&sr=8-9](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593271476)

You could also look at these

[http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Prentice-Source-Software-Development/dp/0132354160/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1301423092&sr=8-2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132354160)

[http://www.amazon.com/Advanced-Qt-Programming-Creating-Development/dp/0321635906/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1301423092&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321635906)