# Show image in a column of QTableView from QSqlTableModel

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qtablewidgetitem

I'm curious about how I can display an image from my database in a `QTableView`.

Is there something like `QTableWidgetItem` that I am able to use it in `QTableView`?

I use `QSqlTableModel`.

Comment: You could look at `QAbstractItemModel::data()` in combination with `Qt::DecorationRole`.

Comment: What's the form of your **database**? Is that a bunch of paths of images?

Comment: yes it's a path, but does it make difference if I store image as BOLB?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A rough idea is to use [`QStandardItem::setData`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstandarditem.html#setData) to set a `QPixmap`(transformed into `QVariant`) on it, then you can set the `QStandardItem` on the [`QStandardItemModel`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html#setItem).

**Sequence:** `QImage`--->`QPixmap`--->`QVariant`--->`QStandardItem`--->`QStandardItemModel`

For example:

```
QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel;
QImage image(":/cat/lovers/own/myCat.jpg");
QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem();
item->setData(QVariant(QPixmap::fromImage(image)), Qt::DecorationRole);
model->setItem(0, 0, item);
ui->tableView->setModel(model);
```

[image]

You will have to resize images or cell size, depends on what you need.

---

**[Edit]**

If you are using `QSqlTableModel`, just keep using it. All we need to do is make those path strings into `QPixmap` and set the item role to be `Qt::DecorationRole` in that column.

As the document says:

> *Each item has a number of data elements associated with it and they can be retrieved by specifying a role (see Qt::ItemDataRole) to the
>   model's data() function.*

To do this, the concept is simple: provide `QTableView` with `QVariant` of `QPixmap` as `QTableView` render them according to [`Qt::DecorationRole`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum).

You may subclass `QSqlTableModel` and reimplement the virtual function [`QVariant data(const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#data) and make the image column return the `QPixmap` as `QVariant`, with the decoration role. So do something like this:

```
QVariant CustomSqlTableModel::data(const QModelIndex &idx, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const
{
     if (idx.column() == imageColumn) {
         QString imgFile = QSqlTableModel::data(idx, Qt::DisplayRole); // get path string

        if (role == Qt::DisplayRole) 
            return QString(); // return the path string for display role

        QImage image(imgFile);
        /* some modification to the image, maybe */

        QPixmap pixmap(imgFile);
        if (role == Qt::DecorationRole)
            return pixmap;   // return QPixmap for decoration role

        if (role == Qt::SizeHintRole)
            return pixmap.size(); // in case need the image size

     }
     return QSqlTableModel::data( idx, role ); // use original data() outside the imageColumn
}
```

Besides, you can also try subclassing `QStyledItemDelegate` and reimplement [`paint()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstyleditemdelegate.html#paint) function to customize your own delegate, but that will require a more complicated work. An example  using delegate can be found [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/18633-Images-QTableview-Delegates). You can paint whatever you want with delegate, [even a button](http://qtadventures.wordpress.com/2012/02/04/adding-button-to-qviewtable/).

*Sorry the code is not tested, as I don't have a database on hand.

Comment: How I should use QStandardItemModel with QSqlTableModel?

Comment: @dare You should've said that you are using `QSqlTableModel` in the question.

Comment: Plus 1 for the cat :)

Comment: @Tay2510 is there a way to use both of them QStandardItemModel and QSqltableModel?

Comment: BTW @Tay2510 I need a good source to learn Qt. can you suggest a good one?

Comment: **For books:** If you want to learn the working mechanism of Qt, try _An Introduction to Design Patterns in C++ with Qt 4_; to learn how to use Qt, try _C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4_. **For non-book resources:** The best of the best is the [Qt official document](http://qt-project.org/doc/) it self; [Qt centre forum](http://www.qtcentre.org/content/) is also a good place to ask questions. Besides, you can check this [asked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169950/what-is-the-best-place-to-start-learning-qt), some good on-line learning resources can be found there.

Comment: really i don't understand your answer, and it's my fault. I should do study some Qt.

Answer (score -1):

I got a question to read image from tableview, so I find the solution as fallow:

```
QImage name_image = table_store_multi_model_->item(i_row,0)->data(Qt::DecorationRole).value<QPixmap>().toImage();
```

Generally, we read data with `data()`, but here need a parameter `"Qt::DecorationRole";`